# Atomic updates to variables in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Say I have a TensorFlow variable to track the mean of a value.  `mean` can be updated with the following graph snippet:

```
mean.assign((step * mean.read() + value) / (step + 1))
```

Unfortunately, those operations are not atomic, so if two different portions of the graph try to update the same `mean` variable one of the updates may be lost.

If instead I were tracking `sum`, I could just do

```
sum.assign_add(value, use_locking=True)
```

and everything would be great.  Unfortunately, in other cases a more complicated update to `mean` (or `std` or etc.) may be required, and it may be impossible to use `tf.assign_add`.

**Question**: Is there any way to make the first code snippet atomic?

Unfortunately I believe the answer is no, since (1) I don't remember any such mechanism and (2) one of our reasons for making optimizers C++ ops was to get atomic behavior.  My main source of hope is XLA, but I do not whether whether this kind of atomicity can be guaranteed there.

Comment: Is this still a problem with resource variables? Resource variable Read() op has stronger guarantees --
 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6360#issuecomment-271741913

Comment: There is still no way to lock a variable in tensorflow from python. You can write your own C++ update op which can grab the mutex and do whatever it wants while it has it.

Comment: For your case though if you are indeed keeping track of the mean try instead to keep track of the sum and count, and if you stack them in a single tensor (so t[0] is sum and t[1] is count) you can have atomic reads and writes (with resource variables)

Comment: Thanks, the trick of keeping track of the sum did occur to me, which is why I mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem of the example is that there are two operations - read and subsequent assign - that together need to be executed atomically.

Since beginning of 2018, the tensorflow team added the *CriticalSection* class to the [codebase](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/critical_section_ops.py). However, this only works for resource variables (as pointed out in Geoffrey's comments). Hence, `value` in the example below needs to be acquired as:

```
value = tf.get_variable(..., use_resource=True, ...)
```

Although I did not test this, according to the class' documentation the atomic update issue should then be solvable as follows:

```
def update_mean(step, value):
    old_value = mean.read_value()
    with tf.control_dependencies([old_value]):
        return mean.assign((step * old_value + value) / (step + 1))

cs = tf.CriticalSection()
mean_update = cs.execute(update_mean, step, value)
session.run(mean_update)
```

Essentially, it provides a lock from the beginning of *execute()* till its end, i.e. covering the whole assignment operation including read and assign.

Comment: This only works with resource variables, so please put a large warning in this answer that it isn’t quite correct.  Could cause very subtle errors. :)